# Subset rows only contain letters in R

Tags: r, subset, letters

My vector have around 3000 observations like:

```
clients <- c("Greg Smith", "John Coolman", "Mr. Brown", "John Nightsmith (father)", "2 Nicolas Cage")
```

How I can subset rows that contain only names with letters. For example, only Greg Smith, John Coolman (without symbols like 0-9,.?:[} etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grep` to match only upper or lower case alphabets along with space from start (`^`) to end (`$`) of the string.

```
grep('^[A-Za-z ]+$', clients, value = TRUE)
#[1] "Greg Smith"   "John Coolman"
```

Or just use the `[[:alpha:] ]+`

```
grep('^[[:alpha:] ]+$', clients, value = TRUE)
#[1] "Greg Smith"   "John Coolman"
```